# oracle 11g dispaly user created tables

Tags: oracle

Hi I m new to oracle using 11g exprs edition and familiar with mysql. We can use the below code to display all databases in mysql

```
show databases;
```

What is the corresponding command in Oracle. Or how can i display all databases. Also We have

```
 use mydatabase;
```

to chanage database in mysql. How can i change database in oracle. I tried to display all owners and their tables using the following command

```
 select table_name, owner from all_tables;
```

It working fine. But when I tried to display tables I have created, by adding a where cluase

```
 select table_name, owner from all_tables where owner='root';
```

it shows **no rows were selected**. Why this happens? Also I am facing the same problem with most of the queries when using the where clause. Without where clause it works fine. but when using it, the result is **no rows selected** for example

```
select * from all_tab_comments where owner='root';
select constraint_name, constraint_type from user_constraints where table_name='location';
```

Is there anything special in oracle for where clause or the problem with my query.

Answer (score 3):

Your username is very unlikely to be `root`; it could however be `ROOT`, in which case you could do:

```
select table_name, owner from all_tables where owner='ROOT';
```

The owner name is case-sensitive, and all objects including users and table names are upper-case by default (unless they're created with double-quotes, which is a bad idea). If you're connected as that user, to see only your own tables you can also do:

```
select table_name from user_tables;
```

And there is the `dba_tables` view which also shows you tables you don't have permissions on, but you can only see that with elevated privileges.

Oracle doesn't have 'databases' in the same sense as other products. You probably means `schemas`, as the logical grouping of objects. And schemas and users are essentially synonymous.

To get a list of all schemas you can query `dba_users` (if you have the right privileges), or to get a list of schemas that have objects - as you may have users who only use objects in other schemas - you can do:

```
select distinct owner from dba_objects;
```

... or `all_objects` to again only see things you have permissions for. To see what kind of objects:

```
select owner, object_type, count(*) from dba_objects group by owner, object_type;
```

The documentation explains the [static data dictionary views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_part.htm#i125539) which hold all of this information. You won't be able to see all of them though, unless you're connected as a privileged user.

---

There will be a lot of differences between the two products; you might be better off trying to find a tutorial that works through them rather than using trial and error and trying to understand what's gone wrong at each step. Or at least familiarise yourself with the Oracle documentation so you can research issues.

Comment: I have created the user as root. Is it automatically converted to capital letter?

Comment: If you do `create user root` then it will be `ROOT` to Oracle, yes; in `dba_users.username`, `dba_objects.owner`, etc. You can also `select user from dual` to see that report it as `ROOT`. All object names are case-insensitive by default and are treated as uppercase. That applies to your `'LOCATION'` table name too in your second query.

Comment: one more dout... in the query **select * from location** giving result and table name is in lower case. So the UPPERCASE rool is only for where cluase..?

Comment: @Shameer - yes, only for querying the data dictionary. (Usually, and if you're lucky then always; it would be unhelpful to try to explain quoted and unquoted identifiers at this point I think, but you can look up the object naming rules in the SQL reference to understand that later).

Answer (score 1):

First, there is going to be a terminology difference when you change platforms.  What MySQL calls a "database" is most similar to what Oracle calls a "schema".  If you are using Oracle XE, you can only have one database (using Oracle terminology) on the machine.  You can have many schemas within that database.

The `owner` in `all_tables` is the name of the schema that owns the table.  Assuming that you created an Oracle user `root` (which seems like an odd choice for a database user) and assuming that you did not create a case-sensitive user name in all lower case (which would create a ton of issues down the line), the `owner` will always be upper-case.

```
SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM all_tables
 WHERE owner = 'ROOT'
```

In Oracle, you do not generally change from one schema to another.  You either fully qualify the table name

```
SELECT *
  FROM schema_name.table_name
```

or you create synonyms (public or private) for objects that you want to reference

```
CREATE SYNONYM synonym_name
   FOR schema_name.table_name;

SELECT *
  FROM synonym_name
```

If you really want to, however, you can change your current schema for name resolution purposes

```
ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = <<schema name>>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the view : tabs

```
select * from tabs;
```

Comment: `tabs` is a data dictionary view that has been depricated for quite some time.  It's also not obvious how it would help to use an ancient data dictionary table rather than the correct `all_tables` view with the same (incorrect) predicate.

Comment: tabs shows the tables of the current schema, so no predicates are needed, just select * from tabs, Never heard it's been deprecated.

Comment: [`TABS` is a synonym for `USER_TABLES`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_5189.htm#sthref2762), and doesn't seem to be deprecated, though I've never seen it used; makes more sense to me to use the common `user_*` pattern to match everything else. (`TAB` [is deprecated though](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_5178.htm#sthref2636).)